# JSONP - “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token”

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am making a JSONP AJAX request and receiving an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.server32.trustklik.com/apiv1/website/reviews?client_id=098jdsahq67tgysfrtf1babza8y97z8h&client_secret=nfijsadhf7843ryuhfy34287yhrfuihf872h4831qzaqwd32qcwqefcmowqkoeqwkfjieuqhixefhuiwrehfo&domain_name=www.uatourtesting.rajapremi.co.id',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/repjt/590/

Comment: The server does not return JSONP. Does it even support JSONP?

Comment: The data you're trying to get isn't JSONP, it's just regular JSON, and CORS doesn't appear to be supported either, so you can't get that with clientside javascript.

Comment: How i can get data without using JSONP? any other way?

Answer (score -1):

Hi your response data is not properly formatted.

I mean it is not valid json data.

Copy your response data and validate on [JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.org/)

nothing wrong with your request. "avatar_url" having escape char

your response

```
 "avatar_url": "http:// sandbox.trustklik.com/media/images/standard/avatar/32E1209610FBED38D1E6FE4C9266BCCF8315DA37.png",
```

change it to

```
  "avatar_url": "http://// sandbox.trustklik.com/media/images/standard/avatar/32E1209610FBED38D1E6FE4C9266BCCF8315DA37.png",
```

instead of having http:// put http:////.

Answer (score -1):

No problem with the URL, only problem with the outcome data which is not in the standard format of JSON : {["Attribute":"Value"]} eigther its single or an array 
instead of using own logic to format the data at the server end use built in functions for JSON from data set or source respective to Technology you used will help you

Comment: No. The response has to be JSONP, not JSON.